# To be truly .Net Core it's .Net Standard - correct?

Tags: .net-core, .net-standard

I'm using the Microsoft Api analyzer and it gives me the choices of .Net Core 2.0 & .Net Standard 2.0. and the "+ Platform Extensions."

We want our code to run on .Net Standard 2.0 on any server (don't care about phones or tables). So Windows, Linux, etc.

That means .NET Standard - right? If it's .NET Core 2.0 & .NET Framework 4.6.1, but not in .NET Standard, I can't use it. (This is horribly limiting.)

And if we want to put a version up (via NuGet) that includes the platform extensions - how do we define that?

[image]

Comment: I'm honestly having a real hard time figuring out what you're asking here.  .Net standard != .Net Core.  .Net standard isn't an application that can be run, it's the format that you'd use in a shared project that either a .net core or .net framework application can reference.  You'll want to check compatibility, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard, but other than that am i missing what you're asking?

Comment: @Phil I'm converting our code so it can run in .Net Core. But based on other replies I've received on other questions, that means reduce it down to only use what's in .Net Standard 2.0. But as you said .Net Standard != .Net Core. So what does it mean in this test if something is ok for .Net Core 2.0, but not .Net Standard 2.0? And the key question for me, to run on Linux, what do I need to pass in this compatibility checking?

Comment: do you have the results of the test?  I'm not familiar with the analyzer, but what you're showing just seems to be a settings page for what to test for.  I can't think of anything that would work for .net standard but not .net core (if their versions correlate), since .net core should basically include everything standard has, but not the other way around.  So if your results are good for .net core, then they should be good for .net standard.  That being said, maybe your issue is versions, and you should be looking at standard 2.1 and/or .net core 3 to be sure

Comment: @Phil It's this app https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/portability-analyzer

Comment: If your question is because when you run the analyzer with ".NET Standard 2.0" checked that the compatibility check fails, note that .NET Standard isn't completely contained - sometimes (especially on .NET Standard 1.x) you have to add dependencies on "Platform Extensions" in order to see all of the APIs that are available on .NET Standard. To check for compatibility against **all of the APIs that are available** in .NET Standard 2.0, you should check the box for ".NET Standard 2.0 + Platform Extensions". If it passes, all it means is you have to add some NuGet dependencies for the APIs.

Comment: To figure out *which* NuGet packages to add, if that analyzer tool doesn't tell you, Visual Studio will show compile errors for APIs that are not available in the ".NET Standard 2.0" package. Then all you need to is lookup the API in [apisOf](https://apisof.net/) to determine which library (and by extension which NuGet package) to add to the project to resolve the compile error.